# Порядок инициализации объектов в Java

Tags: java, классы, объекты, переопределение

Почему результат вывода на консоль `0 2`? Как именно, по шагам происходит инициализация и вывод на консоль?

```java
class A {
    private int a = 1;
    public A() {
        System.out.println(getA());
    }
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private int a = 2;
    public B() {
        System.out.println(getA());
    }
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прошелся дебагером по вашему коду:

1. Создается новый объект `new B()`
2. Поскольку `class B extends A`, то запускается конструктор класса `A`
3. Выполняется метод `getA()` из класса `B`, поскольку он переопределен

   ```
   // Смущает отсутствие аннотации @Override
   ```
4. Поскольку переменная `a` еще не инициализирована в объекте класса `B`, то выводится `0`
5. Запускается конструктор класса `B`
6. Выполняется метод `getA()` из класса `B`
7. В этот момент переменная `a` уже определена и выводится `2`

---

На выходе получаем:

```
0
2
```

Comment: Казалось бы все легко и просто, но вот через переопределение метода и выводилось 0.