# Переопределение переменных в дочерних классах

Tags: java, классы, объекты, переопределение

Насколько я понял, в объекте `a` будут доступны только те переменные и методы, которые есть в классе `A`, но запускаться они будут из класса `B`. Но вот рассмотрим код:

```java
class A {
    int test1 = 11;
    int test2() { return 12; }
    static int test3() { return 13; }
}

class B extends A {
    int test1 = 31;
}

class C extends B {
    int test1 = 21;
    int test2() { return 22; }
    static int test3() { return 23; }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        System.out.println(a1.test1);   //1.
        System.out.println(a1.test2()); //2.
        System.out.println(a1.test3()); //3.
        A a2 = new C();
        System.out.println(a2.test1);   //4.
        System.out.println(a2.test2()); //5.
        System.out.println(a2.test3()); //6.
        a1 = null;
        System.out.println(a1.test3()); //7.
        System.out.println(a1.test2()); //8.
        System.out.println(a1.test1);   //9.
    }
}
```

Как объяснить то, что в 4 пункте выводит `11`? Эта переменная же в классе `C` имеет значение `21`.

Comment: `но запускаться они будут из класса B` - только методы. Переменные не обладают свойством "перекрытия"

Comment: @kami  
`но запускаться они будут из класса B` это к статическим методам не относится же? спасибо за ответ!

Comment: это был не ответ, а "быстрый комментарий", кратко поясняющий причину. Ответы появляются чуть ниже (в том числе - можете опубликовать свой). И если ответ полностью объясняет озвученный вопрос - можно поставить "галочку" о его принятии. P.S. да, статические методы тоже нельзя перекрыть. Это создаёт ряд неудобств, но - пока вот так вот

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошёлся дебагером по вашему коду:

1. Создаётся объект класса `A`. Переменной `test1` присваивается значение `11`. Выводится `11`.
2. Выполняется метод `test2()` на объекте класса `A`. Выводится `12`.
3. Выполняется статический метод `test3()` класса `A`. Выводится `13`.
4. Создается объект класса `C` и помещается в переменную класса `A`. Поскольку поле `test1` берётся у переменной класса `A`, то выводится `11`.
5. Выполняется метод `test2()` на объекте класса `C`. Выводится `22`.
6. Выполняется статический метод `test3()` класса `A`. Выводится `13`.
7. Переменной `a1` класса `A` присваивается значение `null`. Выполняется статический метод `test3()` класса `A`. Выводится `13`.
8. Выполняется метод `test2()` на объекте класса `A`, но этот объект равен `null`. Выводится `NullPointerException`. Выполнение кода прерывается.
9. До строки `9` мы не дошли, но если бы в ней был вызов метода `test1()` на объекте класса `A`, тогда бы мы получили *ошибку компиляции*, т. к. `test1` - это поле класса `A`, а не его метод. Если бы метод `test1()` существовал, тогда бы мы получили `NullPointerException`, т. к. объект класса `A` равен `null`.

---

Вызов статического метода на объекте класса при компиляции заменяется на вызов метода самого класса, поэтому мы не получаем `NullPointerException` в случае, если объект класса равен `null`.

---

См. дополнительно: [Порядок инициализации объектов в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/892940/236980).

Answer (score -1):

Переменные, заданные в родительском классе нельзя переопределить в дочерних.